# subsurf "fills" holes. what did i do wrong?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm currently modelling a skull thingie. Until now I made it flat but when I want to make it kinda rounded the subsurf isn't yielding the results I want. I'm probably doing something wrong.

without subsurf:
[image: without subsurf]

with subsurf:
[image: fd up with subsurf]

so what cane i do to prevent that?

EDIT: wireframe view
[image]

Comment: most probably, terrible topology and ngons... can you show the mesh in  edit mode?

Comment: Try using the *Remesh Modifier* (https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Remesh_Modifier) and then subsurf.

Comment: i already tried remesh. whe the detail is hihg enough i have like 700 000 polys. its baad

Comment: @Laurin Schmidt - as m.ardito said it is your mesh. In a perfect world all of your faces should have four sides. Here is one possible example of part of your model http://imgur.com/ppXdIU3

Comment: You could probably have used a bezier curve object for this instead, making it a lot easier.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos is correct, instead of creating a mesh object, you should do this in a vectorial drawing program like illustrator, inkscape, etc, then export the logo as SVG, and import that into blender, then it would be very easy to extrude it, bevel it, etc.