# Holes being covered by Subdivision Surface

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I created an object that consists of a cylinder with holes in it, however when I try to use a subdivision surface modifier, the hole gets partially covered. I think this has to do with the circular edges and how there's more than one vertex per horizontal line or something like that. It's only partially covered because the circular edge is split into 4 sections, 1 on top, 2 on the sides, and 1 at the bottom. Anyone know a fix?

[image: Aforementioned hole]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82249/subsurf-fills-holes-what-did-i-do-wrong https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/how-to-make-this-cylinder-model-with-holes/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84455/smooth-shading-sub-surface-distorted-render/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/cutting-holes-with-boolean-modifier-makes-subdivision-surface-impossible/